# Python script run but not showing up on Onesignal dashboard

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, onesignal

```
import requests
from pynput import keyboard
    
ONESIGNAL_APP_ID = 'appid'
ONESIGNAL_REST_API_KEY = 'apikey'
ONESIGNAL_API_URL = 'https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications'

def send_notification(message):
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': f'Basic {ONESIGNAL_REST_API_KEY}'
    }

    payload = {
        'app_id': ONESIGNAL_APP_ID,
        'contents': {'en': message},
        'included_segments': ['All']
    }

    print("Sending payload:", payload)

    response = requests.post(ONESIGNAL_API_URL, headers=headers, json=payload)

    print("Response status code:", response.status_code)
    print("Response content:", response.content)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        print('Notification sent successfully')
    else:
        print(f'Failed to send notification. Status code: {response.status_code}')

def on_return_key_press(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.enter:
        print('Enter key pressed. Sending notification...')
        send_notification('Robert is feeling stressed')

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_return_key_press) as listener:
    print('Listener activated. Press Enter to send notification.')
    listener.join()
```

I’m fairly new to programming and coding. I am currently creating a school project that a raspberry pi sends a message to Onesignal. When a key is pressed on my keyboard it should trigger a notification on Onesignal. When I run the code there is an output on the terminal that says the notification is sent. When I go to the Onesignal dashboard nothing shows up.

I have tried to refresh Onesignal

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code.

Comment: Sorry, posted this on my phone! Its updated now

Comment: Is this a one time issue or does it happen occasionally or does it happen after a certain number of signals?  (The latter implies a quota.  The former two implies intermittent network issues or signals being lost.)  Are there any errors?  What exactly gets printed out on the terminal?